# Angular2: different routing for different components on the same page

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

There are two different components on a page. Each component has a main view. After clicking on the "CLICK TO ENTER", the component will route to another view. One can click on "CLICK TO GO BACK TO MAIN" to go back to the main view.

My questions:
1) Is it possible to achieve this since there is only one url in the browser?
I read about named router outlets but not sure if that is the right way to go about this.

2) What if the components are actually modules? Each module will have its own router. I'd like to turn each component into a separate module.

Thank you very much.

[image]

Comment: Both component change when we 'CLICK TO ENTER' ?

Comment: @YounesM, no, they are separate components. Each has its own routing. Clicking on "Click to enter" in component 1 doesn't change the content in component 2.